# Php generated jquery script doesn't work for div generated by the same php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm fairly new to jquery and php, so maybe this is just a dumb thing.

I'm working on a script that retrieves records from a database and print it to the page. Eacht individual task has it's own id. The problem is that I want to add a class to a specific div generated by php. The jquery script that does the task is also generated by php.

The jquery script works if it's just adding class to non php generated div's, but not if the div is generated by php. So what am I doing wrong?

```
function PrintTasks($day)
{
    global $dbConnection;
    global $dbName;

    $dbName = 'db_planner_laurens';
    $dbConnection = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', $dbName);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE task_date LIKE '$day'";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbConnection, $sql);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $Name = $row['task_name'];
        $StartTime = substr($row['start_time'], 0, 5);
        $EndTime = substr($row['end_time'], 0, 5);
        $Description = $row['description'];
        $TaskId = $row['task_id'];

        $DropdownId = $TaskId + 1;

        echo 
        "   
            <div class=\"task\">
                <div class=\"taskControlAndTitle\">
                    <p>$Name</p>
                    <input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"$TaskId\" onclick=\"showMenu$TaskId()\">
                    <label for=\"$TaskId\">
                        <img src=\"mainsource/img/menu.svg\">
                    </label>

                    <div id=\"$DropdownId\">
                    hey
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class=\"taskBody\">
                    <div class=\"taskTime\">$StartTime | $EndTime</div>
                    <div class=\"divider\"></div>
                    $Description
                </div>
            </div>
        ";

        echo "
            <script>
                function showMenu$TaskId() {
                    if ($('$DropdownId').hasClass('showMenu')) {
                        $('$DropdownId').removeClass('showMenu');
                    }
                    else {
                        $('$DropdownId').addClass('showMenu');
                    }
                }   
            </script>
        ";
    }
}
```

And the generated HTML:

```
<!doctype HTML>

<html>
    <head>
    <title>Planner</title>

   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mainsource/css/desktop.css" >

<script src="mainsource/js/jquery.js"></script>
 </head>
```

```
<body>
    <div id="nav">
<div id="navleft">
    <form action="dashboard.php" method="POST">
        <input type="image" src="mainsource/img/dashboard.svg" id="dashboard">
        <label for="dashboard">Dashboard</label>
    </form>
</div>

<div id="navright">
    <label class="userMenu">
        <div id="userImage" class="userImageNav">
        </div>
    </label>

    <form action="index.php" method="POST">
        <input type="submit" value="Logout" id="logout">
    </form>
</div>
</div>
    <div id="plannerControl">
        <div id="actions">
            <form action="addtask.php" method="POST">
                <input type="image" src="mainsource/img/add.svg" 
id="addtask">
                <label for="addtask">Add Task</label>
            </form>
        </div>

        <div id="dateControl">

            <form action="" method="POST">
                <input type="image" src="mainsource/img/back.svg" name="weekBackward">
            </form>

            <p>15 July - 21 July</p>
            <form action="" method="POST">
                <input type="image" src="mainsource/img/forward.svg" name="weekForward">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div id="plannerView">
        <div id="weekView">
            <div class="day">
                <div class="dayTitle">
                    Sunday 
                </div>

                <div class="taskList">
                    <p>15 July</p>                    </div>
            </div>

            <div class="day">
                <div class="dayTitle">
                    Monday
                </div>

                <div class="taskList">
                    <p>16 July</p>                    </div>
            </div>

            <div class="day">
                <div class="dayTitle">
                    Tuesday
                </div>

                <div class="taskList">
                    <p>17 July</p>                    </div>
            </div>

            <div class="day">
                <div class="dayTitle">
                    Wednesday
                </div>

                <div class="taskList">
                    <p>18 July</p>                    </div>
            </div>

            <div class="day">
                <div class="dayTitle">
                    Thursday
                </div>

                <div class="taskList">
                    <p>19 July</p>   
            <div class="task">
                <div class="taskControlAndTitle">
                    <p>Nog een TEST</p>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="1501049399" onclick="showMenu1501049399()">
                    <label for="1501049399">
                        <img src="mainsource/img/menu.svg">
                    </label>

                    <div id="1501049400" class="display: hidden">
                    hey
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="taskBody">
                    <div class="taskTime">04:08 | 05:07</div>
                    <div class="divider"></div>
                    nog een test
                </div>
            </div>

            <script>
                function showMenu1501049399() {
                    if ($('1501049400').hasClass('showMenu')) {
                        $('1501049400').removeClass('showMenu');
                    }
                    else {
                        $('1501049400').addClass('showMenu');
                    }
                }   
            </script>
                            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="day">
                <div class="dayTitle">
                    Friday
                </div>

                <div class="taskList">
                    <p>20 July</p>   
            <div class="task">
                <div class="taskControlAndTitle">
                    <p>Bespreking Fietstocht</p>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="70363444" onclick="showMenu70363444()">
                    <label for="70363444">
                        <img src="mainsource/img/menu.svg">
                    </label>

                    <div id="70363445" class="display: hidden">
                    hey
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="taskBody">
                    <div class="taskTime">19:00 | 22:00</div>
                    <div class="divider"></div>
                    Afspreken data, kijken of extra fietstassen nodig zijn.
                </div>
            </div>

            <script>
                function showMenu70363444() {
                    if ($('70363445').hasClass('showMenu')) {
                        $('70363445').removeClass('showMenu');
                    }
                    else {
                        $('70363445').addClass('showMenu');
                    }
                }   
            </script>

            <div class="task">
                <div class="taskControlAndTitle">
                    <p>Hey</p>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="1130660554" onclick="showMenu1130660554()">
                    <label for="1130660554">
                        <img src="mainsource/img/menu.svg">
                    </label>

                    <div id="1130660555" class="display: hidden">
                    hey
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="taskBody">
                    <div class="taskTime">18:00 | 19:00</div>
                    <div class="divider"></div>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque laoreet nunc ornare quam mattis, quis gravida diam euismod. Nullam et malesuada felis, sed sodales mauris. Suspendisse blandit rhoncus tortor, vitae sodales sem eleifend in. Aenean vitae semper neque. Aliquam maximus tristique quam suscipit condimentum. Mauris mollis nec metus et dictum. Nam quis pulvinar elit, sit amet auctor f
                </div>
            </div>

            <script>
                function showMenu1130660554() {
                    if ($('1130660555').hasClass('showMenu')) {
                        $('1130660555').removeClass('showMenu');
                    }
                    else {
                        $('1130660555').addClass('showMenu');
                    }
                }   
            </script>

            <div class="task">
                <div class="taskControlAndTitle">
                    <p>Kampeerplekken</p>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="1277535331" onclick="showMenu1277535331()">
                    <label for="1277535331">
                        <img src="mainsource/img/menu.svg">
                    </label>

                    <div id="1277535332" class="display: hidden">
                    hey
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="taskBody">
                    <div class="taskTime">10:00 | 12:00</div>
                    <div class="divider"></div>
                    Zoek wildkampeerplekken
                </div>
            </div>

            <script>
                function showMenu1277535331() {
                    if ($('1277535332').hasClass('showMenu')) {
                        $('1277535332').removeClass('showMenu');
                    }
                    else {
                        $('1277535332').addClass('showMenu');
                    }
                }   
            </script>

            <div class="task">
                <div class="taskControlAndTitle">
                    <p>Mail</p>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="1484908321" onclick="showMenu1484908321()">
                    <label for="1484908321">
                        <img src="mainsource/img/menu.svg">
                    </label>

                    <div id="1484908322" class="display: hidden">
                    hey
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="taskBody">
                    <div class="taskTime">18:00 | 19:00</div>
                    <div class="divider"></div>
                    Sturen mail voor het vrij vragen voor de komende vakantie. Kijken of ik heel augustus weg kan blijven bij vhb zodat ik erg veel rust kan nemen en tot mijzelf kan komen. Mail moet natuurlijk wel uiterlijk morgen worden verstuurd anders heb ik een groot probleem. Daarnaast moet ik morgen ook nog steeds mijn fiets naar de fietsenmaker brengen.
                </div>
            </div>

            <script>
                function showMenu1484908321() {
                    if ($('1484908322').hasClass('showMenu')) {
                        $('1484908322').removeClass('showMenu');
                    }
                    else {
                        $('1484908322').addClass('showMenu');
                    }
                }   
            </script>
                            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="day">
                <div class="dayTitle">
                    Saturday
                </div>

                <div class="taskList">
                    <p>21 July</p>   
            <div class="task">
                <div class="taskControlAndTitle">
                    <p>Test</p>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="608646891" onclick="showMenu608646891()">
                    <label for="608646891">
                        <img src="mainsource/img/menu.svg">
                    </label>

                    <div id="608646892" class="display: hidden">
                    hey
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="taskBody">
                    <div class="taskTime">13:00 | 14:00</div>
                    <div class="divider"></div>
                    Test
                </div>
            </div>

            <script>
                function showMenu608646891() {
                    if ($('608646892').hasClass('showMenu')) {
                        $('608646892').removeClass('showMenu');
                    }
                    else {
                        $('608646892').addClass('showMenu');
                    }
                }   
            </script>

            <div class="task">
                <div class="taskControlAndTitle">
                    <p>Afspraak Ali</p>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="1059759060" onclick="showMenu1059759060()">
                    <label for="1059759060">
                        <img src="mainsource/img/menu.svg">
                    </label>

                    <div id="1059759061" class="display: hidden">
                    hey
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="taskBody">
                    <div class="taskTime">16:00 | 17:00</div>
                    <div class="divider"></div>
                    Activeren van office.
                </div>
            </div>

            <script>
                function showMenu1059759060() {
                    if ($('1059759061').hasClass('showMenu')) {
                        $('1059759061').removeClass('showMenu');
                    }
                    else {
                        $('1059759061').addClass('showMenu');
                    }
                }   
            </script>

            <div class="task">
                <div class="taskControlAndTitle">
                    <p>Stuk fietsen</p>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="1075112594" onclick="showMenu1075112594()">
                    <label for="1075112594">
                        <img src="mainsource/img/menu.svg">
                    </label>

                    <div id="1075112595" class="display: hidden">
                    hey
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="taskBody">
                    <div class="taskTime">10:00 | 11:00</div>
                    <div class="divider"></div>
                    Stuk fietsen van papendrecht en terug.
                </div>
            </div>

            <script>
                function showMenu1075112594() {
                    if ($('1075112595').hasClass('showMenu')) {
                        $('1075112595').removeClass('showMenu');
                    }
                    else {
                        $('1075112595').addClass('showMenu');
                    }
                }   
            </script>
                            </div>
            </div>

                        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: can you also post the generated `HTML` and `JS` (from "view page source")

Comment: Why are you putting another function where you can directly append the class and why the same Function every time?

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr See above.

Comment: @UllasHunka coz the funtion is called on different pages in different divs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears on your script part of the code you forgot to include the selector.

Since `$DropdownId` is an id in your html you need to include a `#` before the name.

So something like this `$('#$DropdownId').addClass('showMenu');` I'm not sure if that will cause issues with PHP, because it's been so long since i've written php. But just from looking at it, it appears to be what youre missing.

Comment: Tnx, indeed forgot the #.